# Get all file names from resource folder in java project

Tags: java, resources

Right now I'm manually writing song file names into a String array, then sending the strings to `InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);` to play the song.

I would rather loop through all the song names in my resources folder and load them into the array so that each time I add a song, I don't need to manually type it into the array.

All of my songs are located in `resources` folder:

[image]

Is there a java method or something to grab these names?

The files need to work when I export as `.jar`.

I thought I could use something like this?

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/");`

Is there a `listFiles()` or something for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the classpath is dynamic in Java. Any additional Jar could contribute to a package, a classloader can be as dynamic as imaginable and could even dynamically create classes or resources on demand.

If you have a specific JAR file and you know the path within that JAR file then you could simply treat that file as archive and access it via `java.util.jar.JarFile` which lets you list all entries in the file.

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile("res.jar");
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    System.out.println(entry.getName());
}
```

If you want to do this without knowing the JAR filename and path (e.g. by a class within the JAR itself) you need to get the filename dynamically as Evgeniy suggested; just use your own class name (including package; your screenshot looks like you are in default package, which is a bad idea).

Comment: So I can read one file name at a time but not get all filenames into an array and send them as I wish to `getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. Of course you can iterate over the entries and build an Array (or a better data structure) of the resource identifiers. `getResourceAsStream` takes single identifiers only.

Comment: That's what I want to do. I want to get all song names as strings and put them in my own string array. then load them as I wish as single paths into `getResourceAsStream`. I just don't know how to get all song names from `resources` folder.

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to iterate through the song names in `resources`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Enumeration<URL> e = ClassLoader.getSystemResources("org/apache/log4j");
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
   URL u = e.nextElement();
   String file = u.getFile();
...
```

`file:/D:/.repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar!/org/apache/log4j`

extract jar path from here and use `JarFile` class to know org/apache/log4j contents.

If it is unpacked, you will get straight path and use `File.listFIles`