# How to retrieve image from project folder

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to shuffle image from my folder image which I am able to do. what I have to pass the name of image but I don't want pass the name of image I just want to give the name of folder and all image should from there how can I do this

Here is my code

```
public class main1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JLabel ecause = new JLabel();
    private List<BufferedImage> list = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    private List<BufferedImage> shuffled;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private int width = 700;
    private int height = 700;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(4000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public main1() {
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 0));
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        ecause.setText("           eCause List");
        ecause.setBounds(0, 1278, 496, 88);
        ecause.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 40));
        ecause.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 0));
        ecause.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(ecause);
        initComponents();
        try {
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture2.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture3.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture4.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture5.png"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        timer.start();

    }

    private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

    private void update() {
        if (shuffled.isEmpty()) {
            shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
            Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        }
        BufferedImage icon = shuffled.remove(0);
        jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
    }
}
```

How can I achieve my output?

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for edit could u please solve my problem

Comment: [maybe...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

Comment: Seems [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247898/get-all-file-names-from-resource-folder-in-java-project) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list every file contained in the folder like this :

```
File[] files = new File("images/").listFiles();
```

Note that it will also give the subdirectories.

So instead of

```
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture2.png"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture3.png"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture4.png"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\Picture5.png"))));
```

You can simply loop over each files given by `listFiles` method. You could also use [listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) in order to filter out each file that isn't an image.

Comment: i am little bit confused could u write little code for me

Comment: I certainly won't do your homework :) `listFile` will return each file of the directory. Just use a `for loop` to iterate over them and add them to your image list.

Comment: If target directory in project classpath, that doesn't help.

Comment: He's saying that the original code works, so I guess it does help.

Comment: target directory is project class path

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but don't have the rep yet - doing

```
new File("images/myimage.png")
```

will not work if you package your code into a jar. To do this, you will need to use getResourceAsStream (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and if your images folder is at your project root, you would do:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images")
```

The first slash here is important - it denotes the fact that you are going from the project root. If you just put "images", it would look from whatever class you put this code in (say you were in com.somepackage.blah, it would look in the blah package for your image).

Hope this helps!