# How to get list of resource files in a JAR file

Tags: java, file, jar, resources, getresource

I know this question has been asked before but I can't find an answer that appears to be the de-facto way to do it.

I simply want to list all the resource files that are packaged in a particular folder inside my JAR file.

The JAR file contains a folder called variants and inside it are an unknown number of JSON files that I want to list.

Initially I tried this:

```
    File[] files = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("variants").getPath()).listFiles();
```

This worked when running the program in Eclipse but not when running the JAR file from the command line because the path returns:

```
file:/dev-root/target/my-app.jar!/variants
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28057735/820657) answer I was able to get it to work but it seems overly complex, it's not the accepted or even the most popular answer. Is there a straightforward way to achieve what I want?

**EDIT**

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21248058/820657) answer I produced the following:

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile("target/myapp.jar");
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();

while (entries.hasMoreElements())
{
    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

    if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().contains("variants"))
    {
        // add name to files []
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get a list of all the files in one go using this technique?
 E.g. using something like `listFiles`.

Comment: Try to go to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html. The command to use is "jar tf jar-file".

Comment: @harrypotter The question refers to getting the resource files from the JAR file from within my program.